# Control de Windows Forms de tipo explorador de archivos y carpetas

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Existe algún control de Windows Forms estilo explorador de archivos y carpetas de Windows pero que permita seleccionar varios archivos y carpetas al mismo tiempo?

Algo como esto:

[image: Estructura de archivos y carpetas con checkboxes]

Encontré un un control de terceros en la web que se llama Enhanced BrowseForFolder styled TreeView pero por lo que veo no tiene la posibilidad de seleccionar archivos, sólo directorios únicamente.

Trabajo con C# y Visual Studio 2017 y 2013.

Answer (score 3):

Si puede usar un componente licenciado este cumple con lo que necesitas

[ShellBrowser Components .NET Edition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JAMSoftwareGermany.ShellBrowserComponentsNETEdition)

[FileView Control 2012](http://www.ssware.com/fileview/fileview.htm)

si necesitas algo de libre uso quizas debas desarrollar tu propio user control, uniendo un treeview con el ListView

Tambien podrias ver de integrar un componente creado en WPF

[File Explorer for WPF](https://fileexplorer.codeplex.com/)

al ser un componente puede usarlo en winform